# ExtJS 3.4 checkboxgroup doesn't set value

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I get checked data string: "box0,box15,box30,box45"

Sencha docs says, I can set the value this way (checkboxes id and name are same like above)

```
// use comma separated string to set items with name to true (checked)
myCheckboxGroup.setValue('cb-col-1,cb-col-3');
```

I want to set true my boxes this way, but can't. Have you any idea about this?

Comment: Can you post more code? Show your call to `Ext.Create` or your config for your checkbox group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
Ext.getCmp('MyCheckboxGroup').setValue({
     cbxName: true,
     cbxDescription: false
     //cbxDescription: (condition)  //you can always specify an condition here.
 });
```

NOTE:  `cbxName`, `cbxDescription` are the id's of checkboxes under `MyCheckboxGroup`, eg:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
    fieldLabel: 'MyCheckboxGroup',
    name: 'mycbxgrp',
    columns: 2,
    items: [
        { id: 'cbxName', boxLabel: 'Name', name: 'mycbxgrp', inputValue: 1 },
        { id: 'cbxDescription', boxLabel: 'Description', name: 'mycbxgrp', inputValue: 2 }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at work so i can't check my sources but i recall that it should be

```
cb-col-1 = Ext.getCmp(cb-col-1)
cb-col-3 = Ext.getCmp(cb-col-3)

myCheckboxGroup.setValue(cb-col-1 true);
myCheckboxGroup.setValue(cb-col-3, true);
```

if it is a component, and

```
Ext.get('cb-col-1').dom.value = true;
Ext.get('cb-col-3').dom.value = true;
```

if it is an element

Answer (score 0):

When using `setValue` with a `checkboxgroup` you need to pass the checkbox field name:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.CheckboxGroup', {
    id: 'MyGroup',
    items: [{
        xtype:'checkbox',
        name: 'check1'
    },{
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        name: 'check2'
    },{
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        name: 'checkset',
        inputValue: 'val1'
    },{
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        name: 'checkset',
        inputValue: 'val2'
    }]
 });

 Ext.getCmp('MyGroup').setValue({
     check1: true,
     check2: false,
     checkset: ['val1', 'val2']
 });
```

Literally lifted from the [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup-method-setValue)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the 3.4 version # - my answer may b e completely wrong.